# Is there a gallery software that I can embed on a site, that's simple and I can let someone else add pictures (and captions)

Tags: html, image-gallery

I am looking for something that will allow me to put a photo gallery onto my website. I would also like to let someone else be able to easily add/remove pictures.

It would be nice, though not required, to work with a photo sharing website (like Flickr).

Comment: What sort of web server are you hosting the site on?  Apache?  IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoolIris has XML/Flickr support with a "Vido wall" style Flash component.

No add/remove functionality though, depends on other code to do that. Maybe use this *as well as* someone else's suggestion?

http://developer.cooliris.com/?p=embed

Answer (score 3):

http://gallery.menalto.com/

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use [Coppermine Photo Gallery](http://coppermine-gallery.net/) which is PHP-based.  It requires a database (I'm using MySQL) but there are other alternatives which use flat file based data sources.

Coppermine allows users to create accounts, upload their own photos and comment and vote on photos.  There is a bunch of advanced features which I haven't dug into as yet.  The main website has a complete list of functionality.

Obviously there are also other options for ASP.net solutions also.  What web server are you hosting on?

[Coppermine's Requirements are](http://coppermine-gallery.net/demo/cpg14x/docs/faq.htm#MinimumRequirements):

- Any webserver, Apache recommended (Coppermine has been reported to work with Apache, Microsoft Internet Information Server (IIS), Roxen WebServer, Abyss, JanaServer)
- PHP 4.2.0 or better
- GD lib or Image Magick
- mySQL 3.23.23 or better (4.x recommended). Don't confuse the client api version (which is shown in phpinfo) with the mySQL version!

Oh plus, Coppermine is free software and is being released under the GNU GPL license.

[ http://coppermine-gallery.net/ ]

Answer (score 0):

Can I add xFlow! to this illustrious list?

http://xflow.pwhitrow.com

xFlow! is a gallery application that has been built to answer the internet's demand for a fully functional Coverflow style gallery.

Written in PHP and Javascript, it's a breeze to setup and administer, and boasts a wealth of features, including support for Flickr and YouTube.